# What is the exact sql query for get below output

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my subscription table

| id | active | hospitalId | packageId | packageDuration | expireDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 2021-01-22 |
| 2 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 2021-03-02 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 2021-03-08 |

I tried following query. so, i got max.expiredDate hospitals.

```
 select h.id,max(sp.expireDate) from hospital h 
        LEFT JOIN subscribedPackage sp ON sp.hospitalId = h.id
        LEFt JOIN packageHospital p ON p.id = sp.packageId
        where h.id not in 
        (select s.hospitalId from subscribedPackage s 
        where s.active = 1 ) 
        AND h.hospital_active != 0
        group by h.id
```

- OutPut

| id | expireDate |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 2021-03-02 |
| 9 | null |

below query is ok.

But, if i need other columns also like packageId,packageDuration etc.

- My expecting output is below

| id | expireDate | packageId | packageDuration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2021-03-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | null | null | null |

What is the exact query to get below expected output??

Comment: I tried below query 

select h.id,max(sp.expireDate),sp.id from Follow_My_Doct.tbl_hospital_registration h
LEFT JOIN Follow_My_Doct.tbl_subscribed_packages sp ON sp.hospitalId = h.id
where h.id not in
(select s.hospitalId from Follow_My_Doct.tbl_subscribed_packages s
where s.active = 1 )
AND h.hospital_active != 0
group by h.id,sp.id

Comment: Where does the date 2021-03-07 in your example result come from? This doesn't seem to be in your data.

Comment: If you think you have omitted important details from the question, edit the question. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @dpr i edited result

Comment: @Strawberry this is dummy data

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take your existing query and join back to your `hospital` table.

I would also use `exists` instead of not in, and in the use-case shown I can't see a need for your outer join on `packageHospital` aliased as p, you don't use it.

Try this

```
    select h.id, x.MaxExpiredDate, h.<other desired columns>, sp.packageDuration, sp. packageId
    from (
        select h.id, Max(sp.expireDate) MaxExpiredDate
        from hospital h 
        left join subscribedPackage sp on sp.hospitalId = h.id
        where h.hospital_active != 0 
            and not exists (select * from subscribedPackage s where s.hospitalId=h.id and s.active = 1 )
        group by h.id
    )x
join hospital h on h.id=x.id
join subscribedPackage sp on sp.hospitalId = h.id
```

Comment: If you're using `exists`, then `*` is a bit silly

Comment: Using * with exists is best practice; you could equally use select 1, select 'wibble' or select 1/0

Comment: other columns not in h. table, i need other columns from subscribedPackage table 
example i need s.packageDuration, s. packageId , etc... @sTTu

Comment: Then you can also join back to subscribedPackage, now you have the Id of the rows needed, have amended the query above, hopefully that gives you what you need.

Comment: @sTTu No ..if i select sp.packageDuration its coming multiple hospitalId and same expireDate

Comment: @sTTu Now no need to use p its just joined, it is not a problem i think so